# How to XCode test a string

Tags: objective-c, xcode, string, testing, sentestingkit

I have to set up test cases for an assignment. I know to use STAssertEquals for numbers but I am unsure how to test the following method that returns a string.

```
-(NSString *) description
{
    NSLog(@"\n \n Account information for %@ \n Balance is $%g dollars \n Number of transacrions are: %d \n\n\n\n", [self owner],[self balance], [self numberOfTransactions]);
```

Would I use STAssertsTrue?? If so how would I apply it to the code above?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the expected string result, use `STAssertEqualObjects`.

Since string is an `NSObject`, you can use `STAssertEqualObjects`, and it will delegate the check to the `NSString` implementation of object equality.